# Many to many relationship in mongoose.js

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, many-to-many

please check the schema of **Student** and **Subject**

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
var studentSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    roll: Number,
    subject: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'subject'
    }]
})

var subjectSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    marks: Number,
    student: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'student'
    }]
})

var studentModel = mongoose.model('student', studentSchema);
var subjectModel = mongoose.model('subject', subjectSchema);
```

I want that whenever I save a new Subject its student field should get the  id of the student and corresponding student's subject field should get the id of subject.

I've written following code

```
var subject = new subjectModel({
    name: "FCPC",
    marks: 79,
})

studentModel.findOne({name:"Yname"}).exec(function(err,stu){
    subject.student=stu._id;
    subject.save();
    studentModel.updateOne({_id:stu._id},{$push:{subject:subject._id}}).exec();
})
```

Its working fine , but please tell me is it the correct approach and is there any better way to accomplish it

Comment: Better if you manage another collection for storing data of student <=> subject.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set `Subject` in `Student` Object.

You can get Student's subject by `findOne({name:"name"})`

So for example with `student.id="id"` and `student.name="name"` so for `student.subject[i].id` ( desired subject id ) we can get students that have this subjects with :

```
studentModel.find({

    subjects:{

        $elemMatch:student.subject[i].id

    }

});
```

---

So you don't need to add `Student` to `Subject` Schema

PS : you also don't need to update your datas twice